# How to create an image with plain text?

Tags: images, jpeg, png

You open a new .txt file, you write the instructions there for an image and when you save it as .png it should present you an image. How the image looks is not important. I'm just curious if I could create an image by writing *things* in a textfile.

This is the raw file text from an image I made with *paint.net*. I opened paint.net and directly saved it as a .png file. So the raw file is minimal.

```
‰PNG


IHDR     X   ­¨rB   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa   PLTEÿÿÿ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             #·á      pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d   tEXtSoftware paint.net 4.0.21ñ i•  èIDATx^íÁ
   Â ÷Om                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 7jUÁ     IEND®B`‚
```

Unfortunately Stackoverflow doesn't support all characters so this is a bit vague. But if you scroll to the right side you can see something you can interpret at least a bit. De file is signed by paint.net!

Now to get back to the question. Can I create an image with plain text?

Comment: Short answer no. Use an image editor.

Answer (score 1):

PNG was not designed to be edited as text. Try [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) [emphasis mine]:

> Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) is an XML-based vector image format for two-dimensional graphics with support for interactivity and animation. The SVG specification is an open standard developed by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) since 1999.
>
> SVG images and their behaviors are defined in XML text files. This means that they can be searched, indexed, scripted, and compressed. **As XML files, SVG images can be created and edited with any text editor**, as well as with drawing software.

The code below is the SVG logo from [this link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg). Paste it into your text editor and save as `logo.svg`. Any sane setting for line endings is right, it's [not important](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-line-ends) which one you use. Open the file in your browser and see the image.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
>
>   <title>SVG Logo</title>
>
>   <a xlink:href="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/" target="_parent"
>      xlink:title="W3C SVG Working Group home page">
>
>     <rect
>         id="background"
>         fill="#FF9900"
>         width="100"
>         height="100"
>         rx="4"
>         ry="4"/>
>
>     <rect
>         id="top-left"
>         fill="#FFB13B"
>         width="50"
>         height="50"
>         rx="4"
>         ry="4"/>
>
>     <rect
>         id="bottom-right"
>         x="50"
>         y="50"
>         fill="#DE8500"
>         width="50"
>         height="50"
>         rx="4"
>         ry="4"/>
>
>     <g id="circles" fill="#FF9900">
>         <circle
>             id="n"
>             cx="50"
>             cy="18.4"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="ne"
>             cx="72.4"
>             cy="27.6"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="e"
>             cx="81.6"
>             cy="50"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="se"
>             cx="72.4"
>             cy="72.4"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="s"
>             cx="50"
>             cy="81.6"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="sw"
>             cx="27.6"
>             cy="72.4"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="w"
>             cx="18.4"
>             cy="50"
>             r="18.4"/>
>
>         <circle
>             id="nw"
>             cx="27.6"
>             cy="27.6"
>             r="18.4"/>
>     </g>
>
>     <g id="stars">
>         <path
>             id="black-star"
>             d="M  63.086, 18.385
>                c  0.000, -7.227  -5.859,-13.086 -13.100,-13.086
>                c -7.235,  0.000 -13.096,  5.859 -13.096, 13.086
>                c -5.100, -5.110 -13.395, -5.110 -18.497,  0.000
>                c -5.119,  5.120  -5.119, 13.408   0.000, 18.524
>                c -7.234,  0.000 -13.103,  5.859 -13.103, 13.085
>                c  0.000,  7.230   5.870, 13.098  13.103, 13.098
>                c -5.119,  5.110  -5.119, 13.395   0.000, 18.515
>                c  5.102,  5.104  13.397,  5.104  18.497,  0.000
>                c  0.000,  7.228   5.860, 13.083  13.096, 13.083
>                c  7.240,  0.000  13.100, -5.855  13.100,-13.083
>                c  5.118,  5.104  13.416,  5.104  18.513,  0.000
>                c  5.101, -5.120   5.101,-13.410   0.000,-18.515
>                c  7.216,  0.000  13.081, -5.869  13.081,-13.098
>                c  0.000, -7.227  -5.865,-13.085 -13.081,-13.085
>                c  5.101, -5.119   5.101,-13.406   0.000,-18.524
>                C 76.502, 13.275  68.206, 13.275  63.086, 18.385 z"/>
>
>         <path
>             id="white-star"
>             fill="#FFFFFF"
>             d="M 55.003, 23.405
>                v 14.488
>                L 65.260, 27.640
>                c  0.000, -1.812  0.691,-3.618   2.066, -5.005
>                c  2.780, -2.771  7.275,-2.771  10.024,  0.000
>                c  2.771,  2.766  2.771, 7.255   0.000, 10.027
>                c -1.377,  1.375 -3.195, 2.072  -5.015,  2.072
>                L 62.101, 44.982
>                H 76.590
>                c  1.290, -1.280  3.054,-2.076   5.011, -2.076
>                c  3.900,  0.000  7.078, 3.179   7.078,  7.087
>                c  0.000,  3.906 -3.178, 7.088  -7.078,  7.088
>                c -1.957,  0.000 -3.721,-0.798  -5.011, -2.072
>                H 62.100
>                l 10.229, 10.244
>                c  1.824,  0.000  3.642, 0.694   5.015,  2.086
>                c  2.774,  2.759  2.774, 7.250   0.000, 10.010
>                c -2.750,  2.774 -7.239, 2.774 -10.025,  0.000
>                c -1.372, -1.372 -2.064,-3.192  -2.064, -5.003
>                L 55.000, 62.094
>                v 14.499
>                c  1.271,  1.276  2.084, 3.054   2.084,  5.013
>                c  0.000,  3.906 -3.177, 7.077  -7.098,  7.077
>                c -3.919,  0.000 -7.094,-3.167  -7.094, -7.077
>                c  0.000, -1.959  0.811,-3.732   2.081, -5.013
>                V 62.094
>                L 34.738, 72.346
>                c  0.000,  1.812 -0.705, 3.627  -2.084,  5.003
>                c -2.769,  2.772 -7.251, 2.772 -10.024,  0.000
>                c -2.775, -2.764 -2.775,-7.253   0.000,-10.012
>                c  1.377, -1.390  3.214,-2.086   5.012, -2.086
>                l 10.257,-10.242
>                H 23.414
>                c -1.289,  1.276 -3.072, 2.072  -5.015,  2.072
>                c -3.917,  0.000 -7.096,-3.180  -7.096, -7.088
>                s  3.177, -7.087  7.096,-7.087
>                c  1.940,  0.000  3.725, 0.796   5.015,  2.076
>                h 14.488
>                L 27.646, 34.736
>                c -1.797,  0.000 -3.632,-0.697  -5.012, -2.071
>                c -2.775, -2.772 -2.775,-7.260   0.000,-10.027
>                c  2.773, -2.771  7.256,-2.771  10.027,  0.000
>                c  1.375,  1.386  2.083, 3.195   2.083,  5.005
>                l 10.235, 10.252
>                V 23.407
>                c -1.270, -1.287 -2.082,-3.053  -2.082, -5.023
>                c  0.000, -3.908  3.175,-7.079   7.096, -7.079
>                c  3.919,  0.000  7.097, 3.168   7.097,  7.079
>                C 57.088, 20.356 56.274,22.119  55.003, 23.405 z"/>
>     </g>
>
>     <g id="svg-textbox">
>         <path
>             id="text-backdrop"
>             fill="black"
>             d="M  5.30,50.00
>                H 94.68
>                V 90.00
>                Q 94.68,95.00 89.68,95.00
>                H 10.30
>                Q  5.30,95.00  5.30,90.00 Z"/>
>
>         <path 
>             id="shine"
>             fill="#3F3F3F"
>             d="M  14.657,54.211
>                h  71.394
>                c   2.908, 0.000   5.312, 2.385   5.312, 5.315
>                v  17.910
>                c -27.584,-3.403 -54.926,-8.125 -82.011,-7.683
>                V  59.526
>                C   9.353,56.596  11.743,54.211  14.657,54.211
>                L  14.657,54.211 z"/>
>
>         <g id="svg-text">
>             <title>SVG</title>
>             <path
>                 id="S"
>                 fill="#FFFFFF"
>                 stroke="#000000"
>                 stroke-width="0.5035"
>                 d="M 18.312,72.927
>                    c -2.103,-2.107  -3.407, -5.028  -3.407, -8.253
>                    c  0.000,-6.445   5.223,-11.672  11.666,-11.672
>                    c  6.446, 0.000  11.667,  5.225  11.667, 11.672
>                    h -6.832
>                    c  0.000,-2.674  -2.168, -4.837  -4.835, -4.837
>                    c -2.663, 0.000  -4.838,  2.163  -4.838,  4.837
>                    c  0.000, 1.338   0.549,  2.536   1.415,  3.420
>                    l  0.000, 0.000
>                    c  0.883, 0.874   2.101,  1.405   3.423,  1.405
>                    v  0.012
>                    c  3.232, 0.000   6.145,  1.309   8.243,  3.416
>                    l  0.000, 0.000
>                    c  2.118, 2.111   3.424,  5.034   3.424,  8.248
>                    c  0.000, 6.454  -5.221, 11.680 -11.667, 11.680
>                    c -6.442, 0.000 -11.666, -5.222 -11.666,-11.680
>                    h  6.828
>                    c  0.000, 2.679   2.175,  4.835   4.838,  4.835
>                    c  2.667, 0.000   4.835, -2.156   4.835, -4.835
>                    c  0.000,-1.329  -0.545, -2.527  -1.429, -3.407
>                    l  0.000, 0.000
>                    c -0.864,-0.880  -2.082, -1.418  -3.406, -1.418
>                    l  0.000, 0.000
>                    C 23.341,76.350  20.429, 75.036  18.312, 72.927
>                    L 18.312,72.927
>                    L 18.312,72.927 z"/>
>             <polygon
>                 id="V"
>                 fill="#FFFFFF"
>                 stroke="#000000"
>                 stroke-width="0.5035"
>                 points="61.588,53.005
>                         53.344,92.854
>                         46.494,92.854
>                         38.236,53.005
>                         45.082,53.005
>                         49.920,76.342
>                         54.755,53.005"/>
>
>          <path 
>             id="G"
>             fill="#FFFFFF"
>             stroke="#000000"
>             stroke-width="0.5035"
>             d="M 73.255,69.513
>                h 11.683
>                v 11.664
>                l  0.000, 0.000
>                c  0.000, 6.452  -5.226,11.678 -11.669, 11.678
>                c -6.441, 0.000 -11.666,-5.226 -11.666,-11.678
>                l  0.000, 0.000
>                V 64.676
>                h -0.017
>                C 61.586,58.229  66.827,53.000  73.253, 53.000
>                c  6.459, 0.000  11.683, 5.225  11.683, 11.676
>                h -6.849
>                c  0.000,-2.674  -2.152,-4.837  -4.834, -4.837
>                c -2.647, 0.000  -4.820, 2.163  -4.820,  4.837
>                v 16.501
>                l  0.000, 0.000
>                c  0.000, 2.675   2.173, 4.837   4.820,  4.837
>                c  2.682, 0.000   4.834,-2.162   4.834, -4.827
>                v -0.012
>                v -4.827
>                h -4.834
>                L 73.255,69.513
>                L 73.255,69.513 z"/>
>         </g>
>     </g>
>   </a>
> </svg>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The PNG image file uses (lossless) compression, so you really need the raw image file before you can have a compressed version.  Otherwise that's more complicated than writing a book starting with the table of contents and the index, and then the text of the book itself.

The *"text"* that you see when viewing the image file is merely the forced mapping of each byte to a printable character using its [(extended) ASCII code](https://www.ascii-code.com/).
The only *"text"* that are actual words are intentional embedded text strings in the file.  Any other readable "words" that appear in the image file are merely coincidence.

Since there is an (extended) ASCII character code for every byte value, and there are keyboard strokes for entering each ASCII character, in theory one could generate a file of binary (aka "hex" or "hexa") data using a text editor.
However there are binary editors that display each byte of the file as a numeric value (e.g. as two hexadecimal digits) rather than represented as a character, and allow data entry with digits rather than text.

Regardless of the input method, you would need to adhere to the data format of the file, e.g. a raw data file of a raster image.
Rather than *"write the instructions there for an image"*, a raster image file consists of (numeric) pixel values organized as raster (aka scan) lines.

For a simple image file of 640 x 480 pixels represented in 24-bit RGB, you would need to enter 921,600 byte values in the proper order.
Probably anything more complicated than solid lines or blocks against a solid background requires real effort.
To generate a **.png** file (which is a compressed file) on the fly is probably humanly (and maybe computationally) impossible.

> Can I create an image with plain text?

An image composed of computer-generated text is typically called [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Comment: .png was an example. If there are drastically differences I would be interested in .jpg as well for example. And if I really begin with a raw file, without saving an image at first. Is there a possible way to begin? For example 1 red pixel on a 1x1 sheet. What would that need?

Comment: JPG is also compressed.  *"Is there a possible way to begin?"* -- I  already answered that question.  *"What would that need?"*  -- Unanswerable without an image format, i.e. what kind of pixel?  Grey scale or RGB?  How many bits?  Maybe you need to learn about image formats before you ask more questions?

Comment: No, you're misreading what I wrote.  What is this *"it"*?  What is doing this *"saving"*?  Have you ever used a text editor or a binary editor?